# Is there a way to code a multivariate normal distribution in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to sample from a multivariate normal distribution for a model in netlogo. I know there's a random-normal function but I'd like to extend this to two dimensions.

Or am I better off coding it up in R and feeding it to the netlogo model that way?

Comment: if your two variables are independent, why can you not just use `random-float` for each dimension? so something like `set dim1 random-normal 1 0.2` and `set dim1 random-normal 5 1`

Comment: Hi, it's because I want some control over the variance covariance matrix. Just saw your edit now; I'm interested in the cases when they're not independent.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it's been a long time since I had to do something like this. But you want something like (with rho as your correlation that you control):

```
set dim1 random-normal 1 0.2
set dim2 rho * dim1 + sqrt(1 - rho ^ 2) * random-normal 5 1
```

You might want to check on crossvalidated (the statistics equivalent to stackoverflow) to get the correct formula. But it's definitely straightforward to do in NetLogo once you know how to adjust a normal random number to introduce the dependency. Using the R extension is always fiddly and it's not worth the effort if this is all you are doing with it.

Comment: Great, thank you. To be clear the first normal distribution has mean 1 sd 0.2, and the second has mean 5 sd 1 with a covariance element equal to rho?

Comment: the way i've coded it yes. but you can use any mean and sd that you want for each distribution